# Should I be worried that I might not be interested in the exact type of research my supervisors do?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, mathematics, career-path

I started a PhD program this September and I keep having doubts about whether or not I can achieve what I want being in this program and working with my current supervisors. I'm in the differential geometry group and I'm still learning semi-simple things, and haven't started a project yet. But from what I've seen so far, I think I'm more of a "visual" person if that makes sense- By that I mean I enjoy thinking about shapes and how they change, and if something like that is involved I'm motivated to do calculations. But without the motivation, calculations seem mostly dry and pointless to me. I always knew the first part (about enjoying thinking visually) but not the second part (that without this I don't feel motivated to do calculations.)

I know that it's possible to work in differential geometry and still enjoy some "visual" thinking, but the problem is that my supervisors' research involves mostly calculations. My fear is that I'll have to do more or less what they do, and not be able to deviate toward the stuff I enjoy more. So I guess one of my questions is: is that really the case? I worry that it is because at some point they will suggest a specific topic/question for me to work on which will turn into my PhD thesis and later career. (I know that in US PhD students have a year or two to figure stuff out before finding a supervisor, but I'm in Canada and here you pretty much have to chose what area you'll be working in before applying to the program.)

And if it is possible to deviate, is it actually possible to "make it" in a specific area if you don't have an expert in that area to guide you? By "make it" I don't mean winning a Fields medal or anything, just graduating from a PhD program and being able to do future related research.

I know that I should definitely talk to my supervisors about this but I'm afraid they'd say "leave the program then" because they kind of warned me about this (but I was too clueless to know what they mean back then.)

I would appreciate any advice on what I can/should do, especially if you've been in a similar situation.

Comment: Nearing 40 years since my undergraduate degree and I’m still finding cool new things to be interested in and contribute to using knowledge and techniques picked up over the decades. Frankly, you don’t know yet what you really like, but seem to have one good tool you like. You want a toolbox full of tools to have lots of fun!

Comment: @JonCuster Thank you for your comment! I think my current understanding of academia, at least in math, is that there are all these "clusters" of mathematician doing different types of math, and once you plant your roots in one, it's very hard/nearly impossible to leave and start over in a new cluster. So I'm worried that if I start in a cluster that's not right for me, I would get stuck there. I understand your point about the tools and agree that I don't know what I really like yet, but will I ever figure it out being in the wrong cluster?

Answer (score 4):

Don't let short term thinking dominate your long term interests. A doctoral program should actually teach you things you don't know rather than just confirm the things you already know (and love). Yes, you may have to put your geometric thinking a bit toward the back of your mind for now, but it would be a mistake to give it up. It will probably provide insight to the more computational things you are finding in the work of your advisors.

My field was analysis (classical real) and the insight I gained from a deep and visual understanding of real functions helped with the details. "Wow, a function that is continuous everywhere but nowhere differentiable. Wow." "Wow, a function that takes every value in every neighborhood of zero. Wow."

Yes talk to your supervisors. Yes, keep your geometric intuition. Get the doctorate behind you and get yourself into a tenure-able position. Now you can refocus on the geometric if you like. It might even be an advantage in your teaching if you can communicate that insight.

Comment: I didn't know there is a function that takes every value in every neighborhood of zero...would you mind providing a reference? (one not too complicated if possible)

Comment: (1/x)sin(1/x) is all you need @DavidRaveh, Wow. It actually takes every value infinitely often in every neighborhood of zero. Double Wow.

Comment: Wowwwwwwwwwwwww

Comment: Yeah. It sort of slams into the y axis. It also gives insight into non-analytic complex valued functions of a complex variable. Something I  find hard to "visualize" there.

Comment: @DavidRaveh no, Wowwwwwwwwwwwww Wowwwwwwwwwwwww!

Comment: @David Raveh: Way more wowww... is a function from the reals to the reals that takes every real number value in every (nondegenerate -- here means more than one point) interval. See [Is there a different name for strongly Darboux functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/137986/13130) In fact, such functions (which I believe are identical with functions having a dense graph, but maybe I'm overlooking something in this "drive-by" comment, while I'm in the middle of something else) [can be fairly nice/simple](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/996872/13130) in a certain sense.

Comment: @Buffy Thank you for your answer! My worry is that I might either go crazy or not be able to finish the program if I'm not working on sth I'm interested in. I did my master's in a field I didn't like and it really did a number to me both physically and mentally, so I really don't want to repeat the same mistake with PhD- but I have no idea what to do, now that I've already started a program. I know there are tons of options: Find an exchange/visiting position in another university in a field I like more, find another mentor to work with along with my current supervisors, reapply, etc.

Comment: @Buffy But each of these have little possibility and I'm kind of overwhelmed by the number of things I can do as each create branches of other possibilities an so on. Also, I'm worried that if I stay here and do my thesis in this field that I'm not that interested in, then I won't be able to do the type of research I want afterwards, because postdoc positions depend on your phd thesis and I'll be in a cluster of people working in this field and it will be nearly impossible to leave the cluster and go to another one.

Comment: Yes, it is a dilemma. In extreme situations, consider changing programs. It might cost you a year and has no guarantee that all will be better, but it worked for me in other circumstances. I do think, however, that you are over emphasizing the bad, at least a bit. Someone who knows you better can advise about that.